# How to de-serialize YearMonth with Gson in Android API < 26 / Java 7?

Tags: java, gson, java-7, android

I currently have a response like:

```
[
  "2017-12",
  "2018-01",
  "2018-02",
  "2018-03"
]
```

which should be converted to `YearMonth`. But since Android doesn't support `YearMonth` until API 26, I can't use it in my app.

I don't need any fancy feature that `YearMonth` has. All I want is just the ability to de/-serialize from/to `String`. How can I achieve this?

I'm currently using `Gson`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just should de-/serialize `String[]`. See below test cases:

```
@Slf4j
public class YearMonthStringTest {

    public static final String json = 
            "[\n"
            + "  \"2017-12\", \n"
            + "  \"2018-01\", \n"
            + "  \"2018-02\", \n"
            + "  \"2018-03\" \n"
            + "]";

    @Test
    public void fromJsonTest() {
        String[] strs = new Gson().fromJson(json, String[].class);
        Arrays.asList(strs).forEach(str -> {
            log.info("{}", str);
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void toJsonTest() {
        String[] str = new String[] { "2001-01", "1984-02"
                                    , "1878-11", "0000-12" };
        String jsonFromArray = new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(str);
        log.info("json from array:\n{}", jsonFromArray);
    }

}
```

`YearMonth` was introduced in `Java 8` so this is more generally `Java 7` issue.